# Custom tag handler class with tag-file?

Tags: java, jsp, tags

We can subclass Java-classes when creating JSP...

```
<%@ page extends="my.package.JspPage" %>
```

Is something similar possible with tag-file?

Comment: Interesting question, but why would you want to?

Comment: to output into HTML safely using myTagBaseClass.escapeHtml(string)

Answer (score 1):

The `page` directive is not available in tag files; tag files use the `tag` directive instead with the following syntax:

```
<%@ tag tag_directive_attr_list %>

tag_directive_attr_list ::=
{ display-name=”display-name” }
{ body-content=”scriptless|tagdependent|empty” }
{ dynamic-attributes=”name” }
{ small-icon=”small-icon” }
{ large-icon=”large-icon” }
{ description=”description” }
{ example=”example” }
{ language=”scriptingLanguage” }
{ import=”importList” }
{ pageEncoding=”peinfo” }
{ isELIgnored=”true|false” }
{ deferredSyntaxAllowedAsLiteral=”true|false”}
{ trimDirectiveWhitespaces=”true|false”}
```

The above is from the JSP 2.1 spec, but the story is the same in 2.2.

There does not appear to be a similar mechanism.